# Cross Damain Session Communication

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have two ***domains*** pointing to same **server**, what i am trying to do is when i log in into the application using **domainOne.com** the session is maintained for that domain , if i try to access the application from other domain **domainTwo.com** the session is not there.

> I want the same session values in **both the domains**,

I have **PHP** application [*Yii Framework Application*], and the requirement is, one third party *application* wants part of my application content that needs to be *authenticated*. I authenticate the content using SSO(Single Sign On[JWT]) and pointed their domain to my content(which needs to be shared) using this way, i am able to login using their's(Third party's) domain but when i access the same section using my original domain the session is not there (No Session when using My domain).

> **What i want is, when i log in using their domain and access the content from my domain it should show me as logged in user**

Conditions -

**domainTwo.com/someContent** - *Logged in using this*

**domainOne.com/someContent** - *Session is not here*

and **vice versa**

P.S **someContent** is in my server only.

*Please can anyone help?*
**Thanks in advance..!**

edit - Requirement is the client dont want iframes, please suggest methods which dont use iframes.

Comment: You could set session/login cookie via iFrame on other server as well. So use would be logged in on both servers.

Comment: @Jurik - i didn't you, means what you are saying is fetch content to the other domain using Iframes?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339984/cross-domain-php-sessions) or [this](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/30/protected-cross-domain-authentication-with-javascript/) might help you.