# sharing session over subdomains in PHP

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, subdomain

I am using CI.
I want to share session over subdomains
And I'm using database to store sessions

I've tried this

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));

if(session_id ==''){session_start();}
```

That means x.y.com and z.y.com will use common session
help me, pls

Comment: can you print out `substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100)`, maybe you're doing it wrong there. I recommend you to use `*.abc.com` or `.abc.com` right there. (manually)

Comment: What is the question? This solution seems like it should work.

Comment: Check out the function i use

Its working 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835486/php-session-shared-with-subdomain/17638102#17638102

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the fact that you already know your domain name, is there a reason why you use substr to determine it?  You could would be much more readable if you just used:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.tld');
```

For cookies to work across multiple subdomains, the cookie domain must start with a dot (.) followed by the common part of all the sub-domains (most likely domain.tld.)

Also, the second line of your post, the one where you check if the session needs to be started is wrong.  You're missing a set of parentheses after session_id because it's a function and not a constant. The conditional statement (if) would always fail causing session_start() to be called every time.

```
if ( empty(session_id()) ) session_start();
```

Comment: In your config file, add `$config[‘cookie_domain’]  = ".domain.tld";` CodeIgniter will take care of handling session for you. Make sure to change ".domain.tld" to your domain name (and make sure it starts with a dot.)

Comment: Bro, if I want to share session to http://x.com and http://y.x.com
What should I do ?

Comment: @Mazhar Ahmed - And what would your domain name be? If both of those are third party domain, you won't be able to unless the browser makes a request to those domains itself.

Comment: domain names are http://stsbd.com and http://x.stsbd.com, I did as you told but not working for this 2 places

Comment: @Mazhar Ahmed - So you added `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.stsbd.com');` and `$config['cookie_domain'] = '.stsbd.com';` (with the leading dot) in your CodeIgniter config where the cookie is set? On the receiving end, you can try `print_r($_COOKIES);` to output what it's receiving.

Answer (score 5):

Set a new **session.name** before changing other session settings and starting a new session.
See Notes Below:

```
//Name your session for changes to be applied to.
session_name('my_session'); //Any arbitrary short name. Must have at least on letter char.

//Force a common cookie domain to apply to all subdomains.
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com'); //Change '.domain.com' accordingly.

//Start the Session if session_id() returns nothing.
if( empty( session_id() ) ) { session_start(); }
```

This has consistently worked for me. The php.net documentation on this is minimal, but, it appears to be the consensus with many in the community.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this above would go into the login file that processes the login and starts the session?

I have the code below in my log in file. Yes, I am a cut and paste coder :)

Does this mean it should work across subdomains since it says it's persistent sessions?

```
@session_start();
                    $usersession = generate_session(100);
                    $host_name = '.'.str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
                    if($_POST['persistent'] == 'yes'){                                
                            setcookie("usersession", $usersession, time()+    ($_POST['persistentFor']*7*24*60*60), "/", $host_name, 0);
                    }
                    $_SESSION['usersession'] = $usersession;
                    $user_ip = get_ip();
                    $insert_session = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `memb_usersessions` 
                            (`session_id`,`user_id`,`session_date`) VALUES     ('$usersession','$get_user[user_id]',NOW())");
```