# Getting SESSION Information in Subdomain

Tags: php

I made a login system and set the user panel to the subdomain, but I can't get the session information in the subdomain.

My codes:

domain.com->login.php:

```
<?php
  //Login Processes
  ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com' );
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["login"] = "ok";
  $_SESSION["user"] = "wh1z";
  header("Location: https://subdomain.domain.com")
?>
```

subdomain.domain.com->index.php:

```
<?php 
  if($_SESSION["login"]){
    echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION["user"];
  }else{
    echo "You Don't Have Permission";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Are you forgetting `session_start()` from the second script?

Answer (score 0):

The session itself has little to do with your domains.

1. The session is identified by a cookie with the session id (or
   passed in the url).
2. The cookie has to do with domains: you can make a cookie to be
   accessible in subdomains, but for that you will probably need to
   modify a `php ini` setting `(session.cookie_domain)`
3. And now let's suppose that the subdomain is hosted on the same
   server, and you don't need to share session data between hosts - you
   still have to be careful not to override gathered session.

**Read these for more details, and you will get the point:**

- [sharing session over subdomains in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318492/sharing-session-over-subdomains-in-php)
- [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)