# login to a domain and use the same session in subdomain

Tags: php, session, redirect, subdomain

I have a problem with session. I have website for example www.mysite.com and also there are some sub-domain sub1.mysite.com sub2.mysite.com, I want to log in only once and I want to use the same session data for booth domains.

First it would be great if I log in on the main domain it would work in the sub-domains. I have been read a several forums, and now I'm totally confused. Most of these forums told I have to take this code to my main domain login php file:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.mysite.com');
session_start();
```

So I puted this code to my main login php and I putted just this to the sub-domains:

```
session_start();
```

It doesn't work, please somebody explain me what should I do, what is the possible problem? Also this should handle automatically to save session data's to coockies? I mean if I create for example this session variable

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $user_datas['email'];
```

it should available in the sub-domain as well if it working correctly?

My second question if I log in on sub-domain(for example sub1.mysite.com) will it work to use this session on the other sub-domain and the main domain?(sub2.mysite.com and www.mysite.com)

Thanks,
Zsolt

P.S.: I also checked my php.ini settings on my web hosting provider there is the following line:

```
session.cookie_domain    no value(local value)     no value(master value)
```

I don't know is it good or not...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835486/php-session-shared-with-subdomain

Comment: Use boksiora's solution. Place that code before every `sessions_start()`.