# domain -> subdomain - passing session data

Tags: php, session, subdomain

Howdy, having a little trouble here.
I have domain.co.uk setting a session. When I click on a link on domain.co.uk to go to sub.domain.co.uk the session is not being read.

I have altered session.cookie_domain to .domain.co.uk not still not working. Is there anything else that needs changing?

Regards,
me.

Comment: You should take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains

Comment: I have already looked at that and have session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.co.uk'); in the page.

Comment: I have one main page which includes files depending on variables and whether it is a subdomain ( using wildcard subs ).

Comment: Are the two domains handled by the same PHP codebase?

Comment: Had the same problem, found this answer to work for me: [PHP Sessions across sub domains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1457582/826668)

Comment: Phil, how to specify the wild card based subdomains? like session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'prefix*.domain.com') ??

Answer (score 1):

in your htacces file

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".domain.co.uk"
```

and you're done

Comment: what if you just have domain.co.uk without the www? Wont that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Information about session ID stored in cookies. subdomain can`t read cookie if it is set by main domain. See information about session_name & setcookie and session_id() php functions. Or store session ids somewhere else (e.g. mysql database)
P.S.: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GOsha,

I do all my session handover by submitting form data or storing in SQL. Then recreate your session within the new domain environment.

I'm not 100% sure if there is an easier way?

Not sure if that helps.

Shane

Comment: Passing it as form data requires it to be passed via SSL, otherwise a session hijack could be performed, unless it's serialized & encrypted etc..

Answer (score 0):

Session data is stored in a cookie and if your on the domain google.com then only the domain google.com can access the cookie session data such as username or the session ID.

dev.google.com can't access the cookies for google.com and this means that a user logged into google.com won't be logged in when they go to dev.google.com. That is unless there is some mechanism such as passing the session ID in the query string to dev.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will help you a lot, Just give it a try.it will work 100%.

```
<?php 
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.co.uk'); 
session_start(); 
?>
```