# PHP sessions destroy across sub domains

Tags: php, session, cookies

This could be the sequel of this question:
[PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

I have a successful multi-domain session simply using this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

The problem is when I try to logout from `domain.com`. I have tried everything for logout, even all this, as suggested in PHP `session_destroy()` manual:

```
// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  );
}
```

But it's not working. The session is still alive when I visit `subdomain.domain.com`.

How can i do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't `session_destroy()` do the trick?

Comment: Are you *setting* the cookie from the same domain name, the root domain name (like `example.com`, sans subdomain), or from the "www" subdomain?

Comment: Use a flag in your session to denote validity and set `$_SESSION["valid"]=false;`

Comment: What's in `$params`? Can you show a dump?

Comment: 1) session_destroy does not work, since the session is destroyed with the "setcookie" command; 2) the session is firstly set in the "parent domain", in domain.com; 3) mario, I don't understand you; 4) in params appear "/" as path and ".domain.com" as domain, no clues there :P

Comment: 1) thats why you shouldnt use setcookie(), using session_destroy() totally removes the cookie, setcookie() leaves it but expires it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see if the session is started before you try to destroy it?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE['auth_token'])) {
remove_token($_COOKIE['auth_token']);
setcookie("auth_token", "", time()-3600, "/", ".domain.com");
}
session_destroy();
```

This is working code from my environment.  Hope it helps.