# Destroying a multi-domain session in PHP

Tags: php, session

This could be the sequel of this question: [PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

I have a successful multi-domain session simply using this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

This code is working perfectly and if I visit domain.com or  subdomain.domain.com I see the SESSION vars without problems and everything is working :)

The problem is when I try to logout from domain.com. I have tried everything for logout, even all this, as suggested in PHP session_destroy() manual:

```
// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  );
}
```

1) session.use_cookies is ON, and setup correctly in the server
2) That code kills the session in the main domain, but not in subdomain.domain.com 
3) $params shows correct information:

```
Array
(
    [lifetime] => 0
    [path] => /
    [domain] => .domain.com
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 
)
```

But it's not working. The session is still alive when I visit subdomain.domain.com.

Any help please ! :)

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's not working in all browsers ? I'm trying with Chrome and Firefox

Comment: You asked this exact question before - don't duplicate it: [PHP sessions destroy across sub domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771690/php-sessions-destroy-across-sub-domains)

Comment: Gareth, there's more information here, and I didn't get an answer there ... understand my frustration

Comment: @user311188: It's against the rules to post duplicates, especially of your own questions. If your question is not clear enough for people to answer properly, edit it instead of creating a new one. Editing a question will also bump it to the top of the recently asked questions list.

Answer (score 3):

Simple use [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/session_destroy) to destroy the session.

Comment: obviously it's not working, thiefmaster ... if not I would not ask this :P