# PHP native session issue on expressionengine

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, expressionengine

I am using sessions for my expressionengine project. I have used the following methods to set sessions at the top of the page.

```
    if (session_id() == ''){
         session_start(); 
    } or

   if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }

      or

   if(empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
      session_start(); 
   }
```

I have written custom expression engine plugin where I do session check.

After sometime I observed a strange behaviour of sessions. It is getting set different for different url. for http:// url it sets differently and for www:// url it sets differently.
How do I set and retrieve sessions such that both http://example.com and www.example.com will yeild same result.

I have followed steps from this url as well http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/231468/. I have posted the same issue on http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/232604/. But its not helping me.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: `www://` url? there's no www:// protocol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mishu. After you explained that www was a subdomain and a session_cookie problem, I did some experimentation and then googled a bit.

This post on stackoverflow was very helpful. 
[PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

I opened the index.php file on root folder of expressionengine / codeigniter and then added the below line

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.example.com');
```

Now its working fine. If someone could explain briefly on this thread, it will be of great use to other developers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948340/how-to-pass-session-variable-to-a-page-in-the-parent-directory is also a useful post.

Comment: you are welcome. And that is why I gave the link to that specific function, not just to suggest you should use it. Maybe the system you are using has a recommended wrapper over it, but that man page has the advantage of being a good starting point for understanding the idea (the description and links to other resources); I am glad that you solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

A small note: www is a subdomain, not a protocol. So it's www.example.com, not www://example.com

This being said: the problem is the fact that the session cookie (I guess you are using a session cookie) is not recognized on the different subdomains, so you will need to make it available on the entire domain

You could check this php function for more details: http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params