# Carrying Sessions To Subdomain

Tags: php, session, subdomain, transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SESSION lost on SUBDOMAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324822/php-session-lost-on-subdomain)

I can't use a session on a subdomain @ panel.cyberbat.co.uk

But cyberbat.co.uk sessions work fine, the session is created on the main domain but can't be used on the subdomain, could anyone help me?

FIXED: I used a Coookie instead of a session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.cyberbat.co.uk');` (note the dot in front of the value), that way the session cookie will work on all subdomains.

Or, if you have your own cookies, you can also specify the domain in `setcookie`:

```
setcookie('mycookie', $a_value, time() + 3600, '/', '.cyberbat.co.uk');
```

Comment: Before you call `session_start`.

Comment: Should I put it on subdomain and the main domain?

Comment: Both, otherwise if the session starts on the site where it's not called, its cookie won't use the right settings to be usable on the other subdomains.

Comment: Still confused, I put it on the main domain  and the sub but still will not work.