# Share Session ID accross multiple subdomains / sites

Tags: php, iis-6, sessionid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross domain PHP Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339984/cross-domain-php-sessions)

I have an IIS6 / WIMP system.

When a user visits a page on:

http://subdomain1.domain.com

then a page on:

http://subdomain2.domain.com

I need the session id to stay the same.  I do not need to retain the session variables, just the session id.  Each sub domain is setup as a separate site in IIS.

I would like to configure this through IIS, but if I have to do it through php that would work as well.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for how to do it with PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324822/php-session-lost-on-subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `session.cookie_domain` directive in your php.ini file, or you can use PHP ini_set function.

You change it using [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function like this:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

You should do this somewhere at bootstrap level.
This should work. I had similar situation where I had to create session at www.domain.com, and then use that session on www.subdomain.domain.com. And it works great.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I placed the ini_set value in an include file that was used by all pages, but that didn't help.  I specified the session.cookie_domain in the php.ini and that resolved the issue.