# session id will change in subdomain?

Tags: asp.net

i have a domain ("maindomain.com") and a subdomain ("sub.maindomain.com"). my project is on asp.net mvc4.

user authenticate in maindomain.com and i store user session id in some where like sql and redirect user to sub domain.

```
in this scenario i want to know when domain change to sub domain session id 
will change or not?
```

i search on internet and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311916/share-session-id-accross-multiple-subdomains-sites) nut how can i handle it in asp.net?

my next question is :

```
 how can i transfer data to sub domain without cookies and URL parameter
```

Comment: If you make sure that your cookies are stored without the subdomain (e.g., just .example.com), they will work cross domain. Also, all web apps must use the same machine key.