# Destroy PHP Session Across all sub domains

Tags: php, session

How to destroy session across all domains in php.
I simply use this code but this is not work

```
session_destroy();
```

across all domains means i create a session in example.com that is also create in www.example.com this works perfectly but let suppose i destroy session from example.com it is destroy only from example.com not from www.example.com

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What error message are you getting? Show us more code.

Comment: _"across all domains"_ can you emphasize on this?

Comment: waiting for the pages where you have `set` and wish to destroy the `sessions`

Comment: There is no error occur i use session.cookie_domain=".example.com"; for creating session across all domain this will work but when i destroy session session_destroy(); is destroy session on current domain only.

Comment: @KhushhalGupta, Edit your post with more information. no code = no help

Comment: across all domains means i create a session in example.com that is also create in www.example.com this works perfectly but let suppose i destroy session from example.com it is destroy only from example.com not from www.example.com i think you understand what i want to say @CodeGodie

Comment: @099 i think you might be easily understand what is problem through my comment

Comment: @KhushhalGupta , _generally_ people look at the quality of the question before even looking at the comments. I recommend updating your question.

Comment: @099 Ok i update the question..

Comment: Delete all files from the `tmp/sessions` directory? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MonkeyZeus will i have to do manually again after creating new session?

Comment: Correct. Or you can create a PHP script to clear this directory for you and automate the process.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus But If more than one user session create than please tell me that it will clear all sessions of all users?

Comment: @KhushhalGupta can you re-implement the session create code into session destroy code?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want to destroy the sessions `set` in every other pages already. I will demonstration a little behavior of how it should actually be, and hopefully you will find the place where you were messing up.

Let's say we have a `page1.php` we have just started using sessions.

> page1.php

```
<?php

 // starts session
 session_start();

 // setting variable values during session
 $_SESSION['ID']='13CS54';

 $_SESSION['name']='Muneer';

 $_SESSION['account']='Stack Overflow';

echo "You have set the sessions"; 
?>
```

Now on another page let's say `page2.php`, you are using those sessions.

> page2.php

```
<?php

//don't forget to put session_start(); in the start
session_start();


echo "ID: " .$_SESSION['ID']."<br>";

echo "Name: " .$_SESSION['name']. "<br>";

echo "Account: " .$_SESSION['account'];

?>
```

On `page3.php` or you wish to use/add more sessions.

> page3.php

```
<?php

//yes, add the session_start(); (always)
session_start();

$_SESSION['country'] = 'Pakistan';

echo "ID: " .$_SESSION['ID']."<br>";

echo "Name: " .$_SESSION['name']. "<br>";

echo "Location: " .$_SESSION['country'];

?>
```

Now, on `page4.php` you wish to *destroy* all the sessions made on every page.

> page4.php

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstration are you try on subdomains actually session is created across all sub domain but not destroy across all sub domain

Comment: @KhushhalGupta I'm sorry, what?

Comment: Actually I create a session using simply session_start(); and i use this code session.cookie_domain=".example.com"; in php.ini file to create session across all sub domains and ths works perfectly!!

Comment: But i want to destroy session across all domains

Comment: @KhushhalGupta have you tried to echo and see if your sessions are working fine?

Comment: @KhushhalGupta Read here to find out if youre following the correct path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324822/php-session-lost-on-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to ask was how to destroy sessions on a domain plus its subdomains 
e.g example.com, account.example.com, app.example.com
You have to add these lines before you call session_start():

```
$sess_name = session_name('app');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
```

Check [this link to know more on session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
I have been experiencing this problem, but those lines fixed it for me