# Recover data in Zend_Session_Namespace from other host

Tags: php, zend-framework, sessionid, zend-session-namespace

I have data stored in a session with **Zend_Session_Namespace**, Is it possible to recover this session data from another host using an id or something like that. If not, is it possible to recover the data in a **$_SESSION** from another host?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html) so that the sessions are stored in a database instead of locally.

Answer (score 0):

some theory

[PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

external DB as session storage - best way