# PHP Sessions Between Subdomains

Tags: php, session, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

I can't seem to get this to work. I want to be able to log in from my main domain, and remain logged in when they go to a subdomain of the site. Whenever I go from my main domain to a subdomain, I'm immediately logged out.

I've tried changing session.cookie_domain in php.ini with no avail, as well as trying

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.site.com' );
```

and this in .htaccess as well

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .site.com
```

How can I have sessions go between subdomains?

Comment: Related threads : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains

Answer (score 0):

1. stick with ini_set(); or, even better, with session_set_cookie_params()

## 2. debug your code

- verify your settings, if they actually were set, by outputting them
- verify actual HTTP headers sent by your server to the client.
- verify actual HTTP headers sent by your browser to the server.

Sessions are not a black box; it's just a combination of a few very simple mechanisms such as HTTP cookies, so check every part of it.