# PHP $_SESSION not staying across localhost subdomains

Tags: php, apache, session, subdomain, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

Kind of complicated, but I've got 4 subversion repositories that I want to run side by side on my localhost for testing.

I set php.ini as so:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".localhost.com"
```

I setup my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   vader.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   luke.localhost.com
```

When I login, it sets the cookie correctly.

```
   Name: PHPSESSID
Content: b0d3h7nh5ff40sms26q04oasq3
 Domain: .localhost.com
   Path: /
```

I set the $_SESSION variable on login:

```
$_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
```

Reload the page, the headers are correct:

```
Cookie  PHPSESSID=b0d3h7nh5ff40sms26q04oasq3
Host    vader.localhost.com
Referer http://vader.localhost.com/
```

But the $_SESSION variable is empty.

This all works fine if I remove the subdomain.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Suhosin is NOT installed.

Also, someone asked for the full code for the session setting:

```
if (authenticate($dat['username'], $dat['password'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $dat['username'];
        $_SESSION['userType'] = findId('t_user', 'username', $dat['username'], 'userTypeId');
        $_SESSION['userId'] = findId('t_user', 'username', $dat['username'], 'userId');
        $_SESSION['contactId'] = findId('t_user', 'username', $dat['username'], 'userContactId');
        array_push($reply, $reply);
        $reply['authorized'] = true;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could post more of your code which sets / reads the session?

Comment: Did you do a `session_start()`?

Comment: @SOliver good point; Suhosin may be a factor here.

Comment: Edited my post to add more code.  Also, I checked php.ini, Suhosin is not installed.

Comment: @user1178991, checking in php.ini won't tell you. You need to check the PHP binary or create a file with just `<?php phpinfo();` in it.

Comment: I checked phpInfo, suhosin is not in it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer from [PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains), it shall helps :)

> I don´t know if the problem still exists, but I just ran into the same
>   problem and solved it setting a session name before calling
>   session_set_cookie_params():
>
> ```
> $some_name = session_name("some_name");
> session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.some_domain.com');
> session_start();
> ```
>
> I have changed nothing in my php.ini but now everything is working
>   fine.

Comment: I tried setting the name alone, and setting the name + the parameters.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. You might need to call [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to force a cookie to save before the script ends (or you redirect).
2. Check the default cookie storage place and see what is in the files. This is usually the `/tmp` directory on linux.
3. Stop storing cookies in files. Start storing them in [encrypted cookies](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=PHP&q=cookie&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1) which will free you're server from the unneeded I/0 requests.

Comment: I checked the tmp files.  The session with my ID has nothing at all in it.  I deleted it and tried again.  The session variables are not getting written to the files.

Comment: There is your problem - the files aren't being written too. Have you added the call to `session_write_close()` after you set the session variables?