# PHP Sessions across sub domains 2

Tags: php, session, cross-domain, debian

This is a complement of [PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)
I tried what is indicated on that question, and I see that the issue wasn't given.

So I need to have sessions across sub-domains (`www.example.com` to `forum.example.com`)

What I did on `www.example.com` is

```
session_name("a_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();

echo session_id();
$_SESSION['test'] = 123;
```

On `forum.example.com`

```
session_name("a_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();

echo session_id();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The session_id are exactly the same, but the $_SESSION doesn't output anything.
How to make `forum.example.com` output `123` ?

I tried `session.cookie_domain = .example.com` but doesn't change anything

When I go on `forum.example.com` it destroys the `www.example.com` sessions, and it does the same on the other way, like if it detects that it comes from another sub-domain and erases everything for security.

The 2 sub-domains are on the same Debian server

Another thing that I noticed is that without `session_name` and `session_set_cookie_params` it still has exactly the same session_id, when I set `session.cookie_domain`

Thank You

Comment: do these domains share the same server?

Comment: Yes, I don't know where is the problem...

Comment: NOBODY KNOWS. You have to track it down.

Comment: What I find strange is that when I affect a session on forum, then go to www, they disappear on forum... I'll try to look at everything.

Comment: looks like some code on www deleting the session

Comment: it is apparently not cookie problem if you have same identifier

Comment: It deletes on both sides, and the code is only what I indicated. Nothing that deletes. Or is there something in the php.ini that can delete ?

Comment: Is it possible that `session_set_cookie_params()` handles a 0 expiration time differently than the `session.cookie_lifetime` config value?

Comment: I got a session.cookie_lifetime = 0 do you think it comes from that ?

Comment: Create yourself a script that outputs all interesting session configuration names and their values - including a listing of `$_COOKIE` and `headers_list()` (at the end). Run that script with a session on both subdomains and add the output of both to your question.

Comment: What happens if you manipulate $_SESSION['test'] on forum.example.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've thought about this for a while and I think I've got it.

First things first: since you are getting the **same** session id from **both** servers, we can rule out any cookie-related issues.  Clearly, you are successfully creating a cookie named `a_name` (though I'd [recommend only alphanumeric characters for that cookie name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)) on `www.example.com`, and successfully reading that `a_name` cookie on `forum.example.com`. But, like you said, you aren't getting any data from `forum.example.com`. The `session.cookie_lifetime = 0` is not an issue: that just means that the [session cookie remains until the browser is closed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

We should delve into PHP's session handling a bit further.  The session id you are reading out with `session_id()` refers to a file on your server.  Typically, that file is present in `/tmp/sess_$session_id`.  The contents of that file are your `$_SESSION` array, serialized. (Keep in mind that the data is [not serialized the same way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) that `serialize()` in PHP does... but that's not important right now.).

I think this is a file permission-related issue:

1. `/tmp/sess_$session_id` file is set with `www.example.com`'s user and group.
2. `forum.example.com` attempts to open `/tmp/sess_$session_id`, but **doesn't have the proper permissions**.
3. As a result, you get an empty result when trying to `print_r($_SESSION);`

**Solution**:
Check your server's configuration file to make sure that `www.example.com` and `forum.example.com` are running as **THE SAME USER AND GROUP**. That is critical! For Apache, find your *.conf file:

```
User youruser
Group yourgroup
```

For nginx, find nginx.conf:

```
user youruser yourgroup;
```

If changing the server config files is not an option, then you should make sure that the users running the two sites are in the same group.

You can verify that this is the problem by first loading `www.example.com` and then `sudo ls -ltc sess_*` in your server's shell, via SSH (find the `sess_` ending in your `$session_id`).  Next, load `forum.example.com` and then `sudo ls -ltc sess_*` again, to see the user and/or group change.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When you say .conf do you mean apache2.conf ? cause in here I got the same User and usergroup (default www-data).
Does it have a link to the virtualhost ?

Comment: But I checked what you said (`sudo ls -ltc sess_\*`) and it's the same group.

Comment: here is an example :
`-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 64 Mar 13 18:44 sess_xxxxxx`

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Make sure that `sess_xxxx` has user "www-data" and group "www-data" after it has been set by `www.example.com`.  THEN, make sure it has the _*same*_ user and group after it has been set by `forum.example.com`.  

If that doesn't work, you can try using `print_r(session_get_cookie_params());` (similar to the technique [used here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#104678) ) to make sure those settings are the same on both `www.example.com` and `forum.example.com`.

You're almost there, I think!

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, it still doesn't work, so I give you the bounty, and will try to figure it out later. Cause for the moment I did something else that works fine (a bit like the message under), but I got other urgency to do before trying to fix that problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For this answer I've made a few assumptions:

- The user has to enter there credentials at least once on each domain (any other way would be a serious security issue)
- You have access to either a database or file space outside the web root.
- sub-domain, domain or any other name will be referenced as "site"
- The aim is to have a common file (physical file or serialized in database) accessible from each site/domain.

For my example I will be using a database, since it's the idea I'm putting across, not database/file access techniques, I will have unnecessary lines removed, IE: How to connect to the database.

If this concept is what you were after, or if anyone else want me to fill in the blanks for completeness, just leave a comment. On with the code.


I would take a completely different approach.
From what I gather from your question, and the related post you linked to, you are trying to share a session using a common session name.

1. Each site has it's own session id.
2. Each site has it's own authentication cookie ( $_COOKIE['userid'] or $_COOKIE['userhash'] ).
3. Individual sessions are created, and a common cookie is stored on each site.
4. - Using a custom session handler each site reads the same data. `class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface`
   - My after thought was an even simpler approach, a class that acts like a session handler, reading / writing to a common file. Since php's session handler doesn't save the data until the script has ended.

Original idea - Won't go into details, it's just for reference.

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {
    private $savePath;

    public function read($id) {
        $id   = some_user_authentication_function();
        $hash = $_COOKIE['_h'];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT sess_data FROM login_table WHERE user_id = {$id} AND hash = {$hash}");
        return $result['sess_data'];
    }

    public function write($id, $data) {
        $id   = some_user_authentication_function();
        $hash = $_COOKIE['_h'];

        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE login_table SET sess_data = {$data} WHERE user_id = {$id} AND hash = {$hash}");

        return ($result === false) ? false : true;
    }
}

$handler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
```

```
class customSessionHandler
{
    private $hash;
    private $id;
    private $sess_db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->hash    = $_COOKIE['hash'];
        $this->id      = some_user_authentication_function($this->hash);
        $this->sess_db = $db;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        $query = 
            "SELECT value ".
            "FROM ".$this->sess_db.
            "WHERE user_id = {$id} ".
            "    AND hash = {$hash} ".
            "    AND key = {$key}";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        return $result['key'];
    }

    public function set($key, $val) {
        $query = 
            "REPLACE INTO ".$this->sess_db.
            "SET {$key} = {$val} ".
            "WHERE user_id = {$id} ".
            "    AND hash = {$hash}";

        return (mysql_query($query) === false) ? false : true;
    }
}
$handler = new customSessionHandler('sess_data');
session_start();
```

As stated at the beginning, any code that isn't essential to explaining the concept has been removed.
Things that might not be obvious to everyone:
 - $key and $val need to be sanitized before sending to the database. (prevent injection attacks)
 - The hash gets sent to your login functions, so the hash can be used to clear the session data when needed, can also be used in the authentication of the user.
 - mysql prepared statements would be ideal here, so you can prepare the two queries in the constructor, then you just reuse the statement on every call. Then put the connection close code in the destructor.

**After thought**

There would be much greater security if each site had it's own hash.
Then if you detect a security anomaly, you can just block or re-request the credentials from the one site, without compromising the hash for the network of sites.

To implement this would be as easy as setting up another table containing:
 - user_id
 - site_name (example.com)
 - hash
 - timeout
 - re-authenticate

and modifying the session_data table, so instead of accessing the $key => $val pair by hash, you access it by user_id.


Thanks for reading, hopefully it will be of use to someone.

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I did actually while waiting for a solution. +1 for your time