# How to configure .htaccess in this way?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have installed wildcards successfully. And I managed to make dynamic subdomain to work with a simple trick.

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # *.example.com
        RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?subdomain\.php$
        RewriteRule .? subdomain.php?subdomain=%1&path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Currently in something.example.com is shown the output of subdomain.php, great.

But I want to have it working as I can enter at

> pre102.example.com/folder/anotherfolder/script.php?param=1

and show the output of

> example.com/folder/anotherfolder/script.php?param=1&pre=102

Comment: So you want `pre102.example.com/folder/anotherfolder/script.php?param=1` to **redirect** to `example.com/folder/anotherfolder/script.php?param=1&pre=102` (Meaning it changes the browser's address bar)?

Comment: No, the browser's bar shouldn't change.

Comment: Are `pre102.example.com` and `example.com` served from the same document root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pre=[0-9]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pre([0-9]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?pre=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This does not work. It redirects me to pre.example.com and shows the conent of example.com

Comment: Sorry, this works perfectly. I had a problem with sharing php sessions across subdomains. Solved done http://stackoverflow.com/a/1457582/1502554