# php subdomain session sharing

Tags: php, session

I need to share a session between two subdomains.

I have these domains:

http://example.com
https://secure.example.com

And I tried session sharing with this way:

`<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com");
session_start();
?>`

And this also

```
<?php session_set_cookie_params ( 0,"/" ,".example.com"); session_start(); ?>
```

But both seems not working!

How can I make it works?

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains/1457582#1457582

Comment: What domain is the session id cookie finally set to?

Comment: @jeroen: I don't see anything additional to what OP already has in your answer

Comment: @zerkms Starting with `$some_name = session_name("some_name");` worked for me and some other people.

Comment: @jeroen: it's not possible. The name just should be the same. If you don't change it - it would be the same default value.

Comment: @zerkms It really did :-) And as you can see I am not the only one. But it was a long time ago on a server with php 5.2.

Comment: Try setting a **session name** before it:

    `$some_name = session_name("some_name");
    session_set_cookie_params ( 0,"/" ,".example.com");
    session_start();`

Comment: @jeroen: that's reeeeeeeeeeeally weird ;-) It shouldn't affect it, but seems like it might (according your and other people experience). that's how php works ))

Comment: @zerkms If you find some obscure, undocumented thing that works and has no negative side-effects, just move on :-)

Comment: session_name not works either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I created .htaccess file with this content:

`php_value session.cookie_domain ".example.com"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sessions are shared across sub-domains. Instead assign the value of the session to a cookie. The cookies are shared.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

get the value of the cookie by using this:

```
$_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
```