# How to use php sessions in sub domains

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I have one domain and sub domain as bellow,

```
domain-name.local
sub.domain-name.local
```

I have a login system in `domain-name.local` and I need to use same sessions to validate while accessing `sub.domain-name.local`.

As mention in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains) I have tried following things in sub domain without success,

---

Set php.ini `session.cookie_domain` as `.domain-name.local`

**Results :**

**firefox**- worked
**ie**- not loading while accessing the session from sub domain
**chrome** - not giving any session details

---

set from php code as bellow

```
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain-name.local');
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**Results :**

**firefox** - not giving any session details  ,
**ie**- not loading while accessing the session from sub domain,
**chrome** - not giving any session details

---

another php code as suggest in that question,

```
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain-name.local');
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**Results :** 
same as second

---

Any help would be appreciate since i'm stuck here for long time.

---

**EDIT :**

When I checked the cookies, I can see two `PHPSESSID` was created. I think that is the issue. I need to use the same `PHPSESSID` from the main.

---

**EDIT 2**

When I set the `session.cookie_domain` to `.domain-name.local` from the `php.ini` or `.htaccess`, everything is working fine except in the `IE`(ie 10/win 8). In `IE` sometimes session can access sometime web page totally not accessible(keep loading but no result for minutes).

Does anyone was having same experience on the same issue.

Comment: please read the `EDIT 2`, I follow that question as well, but here issue is different, it's working except `IE`.

Comment: I clearly mention in `EDIT 2` that I'm facing some other issue which is not address in duplicate question. But still this is mark as duplicate which is not acceptable. Please reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to regenerate the session id:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: Probably in the other domain, where the $_SESSION is now empty.

Comment: `session_regenerate_id(true);

ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.first-class-and-more.local');

session_start();`
I used like that, but still results is same

Comment: You should regenerate the session id after you start the session

Comment: then , `Severity: Notice
Message: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`, but result is same

Answer (score 0):

if session handining work not well, you can write your own via session_set_save_handler(...)

but you need this

```
@setcookie(
   session_name(),
   session_id(),
   1400069742, // time + TTL
   '/',
   '.domain-name.local',
   false,
   false // use false if you need cookie accessable from javascript
  );
```

Comment: where do I need to put this code ?