# Getting subdomain session data

Tags: php, session

I have several shops on 2-3 subdomains (shop1.site.com, shop2.site.com) that stores cart item data to their session 'items'.

Is it possible for me, on the main domain (site.com) to retrieve the session from example shop1.site.com?

I have tried the setting `ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "shop1.site.com");` before testing with `var_dump($_SESSION);` but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For must users solved this issue an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457582/2811746) by **@jeroen**. As it is written here:

> I just ran into the same problem and solved it setting a session name
>   before calling `session_set_cookie_params()`

So try the following format:

```
$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
session_start();
```