# PHP $_SESSION across subdomains

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, session

Ok so I have `example.com` which I then use Javascript to run XHR requests to `api.example.com` Previously I had the `api.example.com` as `example.com/api` but I wanted to move it to a subdomain and the sign in worked fine until I moved it to `api.example.com`

I am testing out a sign in script and trying to keep the session live but each time it runs it clears the $_SESSION

**db_connect.php**

```
include_once("config.php");
ob_start();
session_start();
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db_connect.php');

if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ( isset($_GET['id']) ){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $id = 'all';
}

switch (strtoupper($method)) {
    case "GET":
        if ($_SESSION['auth']) {
            $check = true;
        } else {
            $check = false;
        }
        $arr = json_encode(array('result'=>$check));
        echo $arr;
    break;
    default:
        echo "Streets closed pizza boy!";
}
```

**signin.php**

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db_connect.php');

if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ( isset($_GET['id']) ){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $id = 'all';
}

switch (strtoupper($method)) {

    case "POST":
        $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $src = (array)$postdata->user;
        $password = hash( 'sha512', $src['password']);

        $q = $db->query("SELECT *
            FROM users u
            WHERE u.email = '".$src['email']."'
            AND u.password = '".$password."'");

            if($q->num_rows > 0){
                $check = true;
                $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;

                $maps = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
                    $product = array(
                        'auth' => 1,
                        'id' => $row['id'],
                        'name' => $row['name'],
                        'email' => $row['email'],
                        'access' => $row['access']
                    );
                    array_push($maps, $product);
                }

                //$_SESSION['company_id'] = $product['company_id'];
            }else{
                $check = false;
            }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $product['id'];   
            $_SESSION['email'] = $product['email']; 

            setcookie("username", $productx§['email'], time()+(84600*30));

            $arr = json_encode(array('result'=>$check, 'user'=>$maps));
            echo $arr;
    break;

    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, or green!";
}
```

I have tried setting **db_connect.php** to

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
ob_start();
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

But this does nothing and the session variables are lost.

The PHP files are called via AJAX too.

Should ALL pages whether its the angularjs DOM connect to the database?

Comment: Solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains

Comment: @Kepi this does nothihng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.htaccess** on **api.example.com**

```
# CORS Headers (add this)
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
      ## Post the domain that will be doing the XHR requests
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</ifModule>
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
    Allow from all
</Limit>
```

**example.com**

Post the following in the header of your main website

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_start();
```

**XHR Request**

Now we need to post the credentials from **example.com** to **api.example.com** I'm using AngularJS with this

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '//api.example.com/auth/',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
}).success....
```

Also change your config to allow sending with Credentials

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //rest of route code
```

Answer (score 2):

For using cross subdomain session, at all subdomain projects you must to use following code:

```
session_name('SessionName');
session_set_cookie_params(
    1800,
    ini_get('session.cookie_path'),
    '.example.com'
);
session_start();
```

**Important**: it works only if all subdomains at one server (cause sessions stored on one tmp dir). If you want to use similar session on different servers, use SAN storage or store sessions in memcached, etc.

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcache');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tcp://122.122.122.122:11211');

session_name('SessionName');
session_set_cookie_params(
    1800,
    ini_get('session.cookie_path'),
    '.exmaple.com'
);
session_start();
```

Comment: Would every page on both domains need to have **db_connect.php** in it?

Comment: In your case, yes, because you initialize session on db_connect.php

Comment: I would need to have db_connect.php on both domains then and wont this just make 2 sessions?

Comment: It's no 2 sessions it 2 projects using one session

Comment: Just tried it and still when I run the AJAX it sets a new cookie on the api.domain.com

Comment: in api.domain.com you initialized session as in my example ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the session name:

```
$session_name = session_name("my_session");
```

Then, set the session cookie to span all subdomains:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", ".example.com");
```

Then do `session_start()` - it should now work.

Comment: Done this but still no luck, the sessions just die

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));
session_start();
```

At first, it did not work, I had to delete all cookies and finally it worked as expected.