# SESSION between subdomains and ini_set

Tags: php, session

I worked on a web tool that was great and working. I decided to change domain name, so I downloaded everything and uploaded everything on the new domain name.

My login system was really poor, but it worked as follows:

- on domain.com/login.php you provide email/password and on the same page the system checks if they exist in the database.
- If they do, all the information of the user are stored in $_SESSION
- After that you have a redirect to client.domain.com
- Here, if $_SESSION['username'] is set, you are ok. If not, you are redirected back to the login page

To keep the data between the subdomains, I placed this before assigning $_SESSION values:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "client.domain.com");
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "mods.domain.com");
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "domain.com");
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "domain.com");
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = Other-code;
```

Of course, as I changed domain name, I changed "domain.com" with the new domain name.

Sadly, I noticed that it stopped working without any reason..
I already checked all the similar questions here, but even if I follow them and I do the things as I should.. $_SESSION is empty for the subdomain.

If you need any other info, let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

Comment: Someone is building their first XSFR script it seems

Comment: start with error reporting, then update your post to contain what the errors were, if any.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner already tried. Any warning/error is shown if not notices for not defined indexes (for example I use $_SESSION['id'] to display some info)

Comment: *"My login system was really poor, but it worked as follows `<code>`"* - Are you sure that there isn't relevance with the db code you're using? the servers' php versions, the api used... etc. this could be anything. If you say it used to work, then something went South somewhere.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no because if I run the login script IN the subdomain, everything is okay and I can use the session values everywhere. If I run the login script on the main website in the login page, I can't use it in subdomains. It is really strange because All i changed was the "domain.com" value

Comment: Yours doesn't contain the slash as per this example `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.some_domain.com');` and most often times, they're required. Plus, if you already tried that, make sure that something isn't being cached, or the sessions/cookies haven't been deleted. If they're still in memory/cache somewhere, then that could be part of the problem. This could be just a silly little thing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner tried with session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com'); but nothing. And I am sure it is something silly... but It has been an hour now.. and everything is exactly the same it was on the previous domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ini_set("display_errors","on")` on first line to see if there are any errors.

Of the first 4 lines, remove these 3 lines

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "client.domain.com");
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "mods.domain.com");
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "domain.com");
```

and change the last line to

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");
```

After login success and before login call `session_regenerate_id()` to change your session id. As suggested by jeroen in [php-sessions-across-sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains) you can also add the below 2 lines prior to `session_start`

```
$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
```

please keep in mind that if you are going to add the 2 line above, you also need to add them in your login page.

and as a final note, check if there's anything output to browser prior to `session_start`, if so**your setting for session will not be active and won't work**

Comment: Thanks for your help. Anyway, nothing changed. Once in the subdomain, this is the result of a var_dump on $_SESSION: array(0) { }

Comment: have you checked [php-sessions-across-sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)

Comment: tried, but nothing changed. $_SESSION is still empty

Comment: can you post your phpinfo on your question?

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you try it now. P.S. please don't post sensitive data on pastebin for your own security. Nice template on your website though. me gusta ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163602/discussion-between-nic-and-cemal).