# Access SESSION data between subdomains with different servers and PHP versions

Tags: php, session, subdomain

My university (`example.edu`) has a WordPress based portal site (`portal.example.edu`).We've created a PHP app that is now hosted on (`test.example.edu`). What I want to do is share a session variable called `$_SESSION['username']` (which holds the username of the student/faculty/staff currently logged in) that I guarantee is on `portal.example.edu` and share with the PHP app I built on `test.example.edu`. I need to use that to authenticate if that person should have access to that app from their username. Few things: `portal.example.edu` and `test.example.edu` are different servers, and use different PHP versions, although under same domain `example.edu`. What would be the most securest way to get the username session variable from `portal.example.edu` so that I can only allow certain people to have access to this app? I have tried things like  `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.edu' );` on my PHP app before `sesison_start()` and other few things from StackOverflow but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: There are a few examples in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064243/296555. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: The fact that these subdomains are on different servers excludes a lot of standard solutions. Could you put some extra PHP code on the WordPress based portal site that can be accessed from `test.example.edu`?